# How to empty fields after submit a form using vuejs and show success message

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm saving data in using Vue js my data is saved but I have a problem that after submitting my form fields cant empty and no nay success message comes. Please guide me I'm new in Vue js.

**script code**

```
methods: {
addLine: function() {
  this.form.products.push({name: '', price: 0, qty: 1});
},
remove: function(product) {
  this.form.products.$remove(product);
},
create: function() {
  this.isProcessing = true;
  this.$http.post('/admin/invoice', this.form)
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.data.created) {
        window.location = '/admin/invoice/' + response.data.id;
      } else {
        this.isProcessing = false;
      }
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      this.isProcessing = false;
      Vue.set(this.$data, 'errors', response.data);
    })
},
```

please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be something about your ```response.data.created```. Look like that condition is not true. Can you add ```console.log(response)``` at first into the ```.then()``` section and then add the result into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two examples

#1 if you're not using v-model

```
<form ref="form_1" @submit="submitForm">
</form>

<script>
   methods: {
      submitForm(){
         // Your form submission
         this.$refs.form_1.reset(); // This will clear the form
      }
   }
</script>
```

#2 If you're using v-model

```
// template
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
  <input type="text" v-model="form.first_name">
  <input type="text" v-model="form.last_name">
</form>

// the script
data() {
  return {
     form: {
       first_name: null,
       last_name: null
    }
  }
},
methods: {
   submitForm() {
      // Reset form
      this.form.first_name = null;
      this.form.last_name = null
   }
}
```